# C++ ARRAYS Сортировка

Tags: c++, массивы, математика, матрицы, олимпиада

У меня есть массив размерности n*n,у меня есть идея чтобы отсортировать его  так, чтобы на месте первой строки был первый столбик, на месте второй строки второй столбик и т.д. Как это можно реализовать?)

Пытался делать через фор + счётчик, но всё шло коту под хвост(

https://www.eolymp.com/ru/contests/29833/problems/347361

Comment: Это называется *транспонирование*...

Comment: буду знать) спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Это называется транспонирование...

```
int a[n][n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
for(int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
{
    int tmp = a[i][j];
    a[i][j] = a[j][i];
    a[j][i] = tmp;
}
```

Примерно [так](https://ideone.com/ppdC9c). Это то, что вы хотели?

**Update**

В вашей задаче не нужны никакие сортировки/транспонирования. Даже матрица не нужна...

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int x, n;
    cin >> x >> n;
    vector<bool> v(n,false);
    for(int y, i = 0; i < n*n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> y;
        if (x == y) v[i%n] = true;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << (v[i]? "YES" : "NO") << "\n";

}
```

Comment: я хочу сделать с одномерным массивом

Comment: Вы же говорили о массиве NxN? Если это одномерный массив длиной N^2, то какие тут "столбики", да еще в количестве, равном числу строк?

Comment: сейчас покажу задачу которую решаю

Comment: добавил фото…..

Comment: Лучше бы URL :)

Comment: сделал:).??:!.:.

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.

Comment: спасибо большое))!

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа; большое спасибо — щелчок на "птичке" там же...